# how to set default index to index.html

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am building wordpress site and it's not finished yet.
I want to redirect the visitors visiting http://domain.com to http://domain.com/under-construction but i want to be able to see my index.php...

I tried changing the names to index.html index.htm default.asp .....  none of them worked.

and if I used `htaccess` it redirected all my pages to index.html so it doesnt work.

Any ideas? Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

In your root blog directory place this in your .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

Comment: tried that:( but then it redirects my index.php to index.html and i cant see my posts because wordpress cant find index.php

Comment: That shouldn't be happening with that code. Try adding `index.php` to the end of it and see what happens.`

Answer (score 1):

There's a plugin you could use: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/maintenance-mode/

Answer (score 0):

In /.htaccess write as suggested by Sudhir. In /index.php write require('./under-construction/wp-blog-header.php');. No .htaccess in /under-construction/ and in /under-construction/index.php write require('./wp-blog-header.php');. Thats how it works in my case.